# What is the stochastic analogue of convergence to the global minimizer when iterates are stochastic?

Tags: optimization, stochastic-processes, convex-optimization, stochastic-analysis

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable and strongly convex function with $m>0$ as follows:
$$
f(y) \geq f(x) + \nabla f(x)^T(y-x) + \frac{m}{2}||x-y||^2 \quad \forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n
$$
Also, let $(x_k)_{k\ge 0}$ be a given sequence such that the corresponding function value sequence is nonincreasing, i.e., $(f(x_k))_{k\ge 0}$.
Then, one can show $x_k\to x_*$ where $x_*$ is the unique global minimizer of $f(x)$. To show this we need to use the following assumptions:

1. Nonincreasing sequence, i.e., $(f(x_k))_{k\ge 0}$
2. $\nabla f(x_*)=0$

**Question:**

What is the stochastic analogue of the above case?
Is it $ \lim\limits_{k\to \infty}\text{Prob}\{ \|x_k- x_*\|> \epsilon \} =0 $ for a random sequence of $(x_k)_{k\ge 0}$.
If so, how one can prove this and what conditions he should impose to get this result.
I really appreciate if you can introduce some references that solves my problem.

Comment: The fact that sequence is nonincreasing is usually not enough. Also, the optimum is found via an iterative algorithm and the convergence properties heavily rely on that choice. Without this information is not possible to give a proper answer. Finally, it will need to be clarified how randomness enters that algorithm.

Comment: If we assume $x_k$ is i.i.d. I don't see how this converges to a point. Are you trying to use some kind of Markov process?

Comment: There is not reason to assume that the $x_k$ are i.i.d. If you have an algorithm that generates a sequence of points based on some formula that maps $x_k$ to $x_{k+1}$, then the sequence does not consist of i.i.d. random variables.

Comment: @obareey: $x_{k+1}$ is a function of $x_k$. If that is the case, can I use Markov process.

Comment: @KBS: the randomness comes from the stochastic approximation of the gradient. If we update $x_{k+1}$ using approximation of the gradient, then the sequence become random. As a consequence the function value sequence is no longer decreasing.

Comment: @Sepide If $x_{k+1}$ depends on $x_k$, then the iterative algorithm can be seen as a discrete-time Markov process or a discrete-time stochastic process, which can be studied using standard tools. Note also that it is not because the sequence is not decreasing that it does not converge. It can converge non monotonically. Finally, decreasing is only meaningful when $x_k$ is a scalar and this does not mean much when it is a vector. This is the reason why Lyapunov functions are used.

Comment: So the convex function $f$ acts like a Lyapunov function for your case. Quick search on "stochastic Lyapunov function" yielded some articles like https://arxiv.org/pdf/1902.04332.pdf. There are some definitions and lemmas inside it that you might find useful. Basically, it defines the "stability in probabiliry" similar to your definition and stability conditions are given with conditional expectation on the Lyapunov function. In particular Lemma 1 and 2 might be of interest to you.

Comment: @obareey No, not really. The function $f$ is the cost we want to minimize. There is nothing random here. The randomness appears in the calculation of the gradient in the algorithm used to find the minimum; e.g. Gradient descent. So, if a Lyapunov function needs to be built, it is for the iterative algorithm itself.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to explain what stochastic version of the algorithm you consider for solving your problem. Right now, the problem you are stating in deterministic and there is no algorithm involved for solving the problem; i.e. finding the minimum of $f$.

In any way, since you can view an iterative algorithm as a discrete-time dynamical system, then one can define a stochastic version of the algorithm as a stochastic discrete-time dynamical system. Many concepts of convergence exist for such the solutions of such systems such as convergence in probability (which is the one you describe) almost sure convergence, convergence in distribution, and moment convergence such as in mean and mean-square.

Very often, convergence properties of discrete-time dynamical systems are shown by constructing Lyapunov functions which are decreasing, in a certain sense, along the trajectories of the algorithm/system.

Any resource on stochastic discrete-time system will be a good starting point such as the books by Söderström, "Discrete-time Stochastic Systems", van Schuppen, "Control and System Theory of Discrete-Time Stochastic Systems", and Dragan, Morozan, and Stoica, "Mathematical methods in robust control of discrete-time linear stochastic systems".

You can also check the Wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables

Many researchers have worked and are still working on the analysis of convergence of (stochastic) algorithms using tools for dynamical systems theory. You may check the works by Lessard, Scherer, Ebenbauer, Hu, Seiler, Rantzer, etc.

Comment: with all due respect you are not answering my question. What you have explained can be casted as a comment for the question. Can you please post it as comment or remove it so that other people still think about my question.

Comment: The text is too long for being a comment, this is the reason why I had to write it as an answer. Secondly, I do provide answers to your vague question, for which I have asked for some clarifications - which you have not provided so far. I am updating my answer with more references as you have asked.

Comment: I answered your questions, please let me know if still is not clear.

Comment: @Sepide I have updated my answer.